# How to save ACF select field value(location drop down) in my product publish page?

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

In my website i have a dropdown box generate by ACF select field, I used some custom code to display it on frontend. My problem is when I select a value from that [dropdown box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFUei.png) and save it but that value is  not saving in the WordPress product publish page(check [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9lfA8.png) it always select default value).I used some save codes but nothing work. What I'm doing wrong in the code.

**Both codes in the child theme/funtion.php**

1. **This is the drop down box display code**

add_action( 'dokan_new_product_after_product_tags','new_product_field',5);

```
    function new_product_field(){ 
    
    $field_key = "field_601141959f1ad";
            $field = get_field_object($field_key);
    
            if( $field )
            {
                echo '<div class="acf-task-difficulty-values">';
    echo'<select class="dokan-form-control" name="plocation">';
    echo'<option value="0">&#8211;Select a location&#8211</option>';
                    foreach( $field['choices'] as $k => $v )
                    {
    
                       
                  echo'<option class="level-0" value=.'.$k.'>' . $v . '</option>';
                    }
    echo'</select>';
                echo '</div>';echo"<br>";
            }
```

2. **This is the save code I used**

   ```
   add_action( 'dokan_new_product_added','save_loc', 10, 2 );

   add_action( 'dokan_product_updated', 'save_loc', 10, 2 );

   function save_loc($product_id, $postdata){

   if ( ! dokan_is_user_seller( get_current_user_id() ) ) {
           return;
       }
   if ( ! empty( $postdata['plocation'] ) ) {
           update_post_meta( $product_id, 'plocation', $postdata['plocation'] );
       }
   }
   ```

This the my [field settings.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gHzXA.png)

Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Guys i found the problem of my code,the problem is not coming from the save code its coming from the dropdown display code.

**The wrong code**

```
echo'<option class="level-0" value=.'.$k.'>' . $v . '</option>';
```

Problem  of this line,  option value is wrong that why data not saving this that way i fix it.

**The Correct code**

```
echo'<option class="level-0" value='.$v.'>' . $v. '</option>';
```

- If you use the correct code there is some other problem coming. when
  you are using  two words in your drop down box, that values are not
  going to save.
- so I found a method to fix that too. You have to use the html space tag -
  **&nbsp**  in your ACF select field choices. For more info Check [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDLhz.png).when you add your values to the your ACF select field it will show in the website like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlEnK.png).

So that's it. hope some one will get the help.

thank you,
ashen

Comment: Your method to fix the problem with a space in the value is rather the wrong one. Using quotes around the attributes values would be the correct one.